# Java - PDFBox - ReplaceString - Issues with parsed tokens (possibly encoding?)

Tags: java, parsing, pdf, encoding, pdfbox

I've been struggling with an issue related to PDFBox and PDF editing. I have been assigned the task to edit a couple of strings given a PDF file, and to output a mirrored version of the files with the edited strings into it. I've been told that the problem has been solved in the past using this tool, so I have been told to do the same. The function I am using is this :

```
  public void doIt( String inputFile, String outputFile, String strToFind, String message)
    throws IOException, COSVisitorException
{
    // the document
    PDDocument doc = null;
    try
    {
        doc = PDDocument.load( inputFile );
        List pages = doc.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();
        for( int i=0; i<pages.size(); i++ )
        {
            PDPage page = (PDPage)pages.get( i );
            PDStream contents = page.getContents();
            PDFStreamParser parser = new PDFStreamParser(contents.getStream() );
            parser.parse();
            List tokens = parser.getTokens();
            for( int j=0; j<tokens.size(); j++ )
            {
                Object next = tokens.get( j );
                if( next instanceof PDFOperator )
                {
                    PDFOperator op = (PDFOperator)next;
                    //Tj and TJ are the two operators that display
                    //strings in a PDF
                    if( op.getOperation().equals( "Tj" ) )
                    {
                        //Tj takes one operator and that is the string
                        //to display so lets update that operator
                        COSString previous = (COSString)tokens.get( j-1 );
                        String string = previous.getString();
                        string = string.replaceFirst( strToFind, message );
                        previous.reset();
                        previous.append( string.getBytes("ISO-8859-1") );
                    }
                    else if( op.getOperation().equals( "TJ" ) )
                    {
                        COSArray previous = (COSArray)tokens.get( j-1 );
                        for( int k=0; k<previous.size(); k++ )
                        {
                            Object arrElement = previous.getObject( k );
                            if( arrElement instanceof COSString )
                            {
                                COSString cosString = (COSString)arrElement;
                                String string = cosString.getString();
                                string = string.replaceFirst( strToFind, message );
                                cosString.reset();
                                cosString.append( string.getBytes("ISO-8859-1") );
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            //now that the tokens are updated we will replace the
            //page content stream.
            PDStream updatedStream = new PDStream(doc);
            OutputStream out = updatedStream.createOutputStream();
            ContentStreamWriter tokenWriter = new ContentStreamWriter(out);
            tokenWriter.writeTokens( tokens );
            page.setContents( updatedStream );
        }
        doc.save( outputFile );
    }
    finally
    {
        if( doc != null )
        {
            doc.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Which is the code that is being used in a file contained into the PDFBox examples (https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/pdfbox/tags/1.5.0/pdfbox/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/pdmodel/ReplaceString.java).

The file I have been given, however, is not being modified at all from this function. Nothing happens at all. Upon further inspection, I decided to analyze the sequencing of the tokens produced from the parser. The file is being parsed correctly in everything other than the COSString elements, which contain gibberish characters that look like they have been wrongly encoded (bunch of random symbols and numbers). I tried parsing other documents, and the function works with some of them, but not on everything I passed as input (a latex output file was modified correctly and had correctly encoded COSStrings, whereas other automatically generated pdfs produced no results with gibberish COSString content). I am also fairly sure the rest of the structure is being read correctly, since I rebuild the output on a different file, and the output file looks exactly the same as the input, which seems to mean that the file structure is being analyzed correctly.The file contains Identity-H encoded fonts.

I tried parsing the very same file using the PDFTextStripper (which extracts text from PDFs), and the parsing output from there returns the correct text output, using this:

```
 PDFTextStripper pdfStripper = new PDFTextStripper("UTF-8");
            String result = pdfStripper.getText(doc);
            System.out.println(result);
```

Could it be an encoding issue? Can I tell the PDFStreamParser (or whoever holds the responsability) to force an encoding on read? Is it even an encoding issue, since the text extraction is working correctly?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Some files use font subsets. Lets say that the subset uses only the characters E, G, L, and O. So GOOGLE would appear in the file as hex byte values 2, 4, 4, 2, 3, and 1.

Now if you want to change GOOGLE into APPLE you'll have three problems:

1) your subset doesn't contain the characters A, L and P

2) the size will be different

3) It is quite possible that the string you're searching is splitted in several parts.

Btw the current version is 1.8.10. The ReplaceString utility has been removed in the upcoming 2.0 version to avoid giving the illusion that characters can easily be replaced.

This answer is somewhat speculative, because you haven't linked to a PDF.

Comment: Your answer gave me a good lead to work on. Turns out that the PDF I was working on did not use standard Tj tags to input text, but instead used  a PDXObject dictionary which contained mappings of the inserted strings and coded them in as external objects. Thanks for answering!

Answer (score 0):

Inside PDF text can be stored at two places:

1. Content stream
2. X Object inside Resource

Inside content stream mostly text are associated with TJ or Tj operator. But texts associated with Tj or TJ are not always in ASCII format, it may be some byte values. We can extract text from these byte value after mapping character codes to unicode values using proper encoding and mapping. While extracting text we use mapping and encoding, but we do not have a reverse mapping to check if a glyph belong to which character code. So basically we should replace character codes of string to be replaced with character codes of new string.

Example:

```
1. (Text) Tj
2. (12 45 5 3)Tj
```

Also we should replace string in content stream as well as X Object (if present) inside resource.

So I think this might be helpful.

GoodLuck!

Comment: *"Inside PDF text can be stored at two places:"* - some PDF processors (which try to make text non-extractable) put it in a third place: Patterns with page-sized tiles with which a page is filled.